# Angular Auth OIDC; Azue B2C : Getting user profile loading and promise uncaught error after getting Token from Azure

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, angular-promise, angular9

I have implemented auth authentication in Angular 9 app with Azure B2C with using angular-oauth2-oidc library and have successfully managed to get token however I am getting 'Uncaught (in promise)' and error 'loading user info TypeError' error the same time.

### user profile error

[image]

### Promise Uncaught Error

[image]

### Auth Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnInit{

_accessToken: string; 
_idToken: string;

private isAuthenticatedSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public isAuthenticated$ = this.isAuthenticatedSubject$.asObservable();
private isDoneLoadingSubject$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
public isDoneLoading$ = this.isDoneLoadingSubject$.asObservable();

public canActivateProtectedRoutes$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest([
    this.isAuthenticated$,
    this.isDoneLoading$
  ]).pipe(map(values => values.every(b => b)));


constructor(
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private router: Router

){
     //debugging - Capture Error Events
     this.oauthService.events.subscribe(event =>{
        if(event instanceof OAuthErrorEvent){
            console.error(event);
        }
        else{
            console.warn(event);
        }
      });
      
   
    console.warn('Noticed changes to access_token (most likely from another tab), updating isAuthenticated');
    this.isAuthenticatedSubject$.next(this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken());

    this.oauthService.events
    .subscribe(_ => {
      this.isAuthenticatedSubject$.next(this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken());
    });

    this.oauthService.events
    .pipe(filter(e => ['token_received'].includes(e.type)))
    .subscribe(e => this.oauthService.loadUserProfile());

    this.oauthService.events
     .pipe(filter(e => ['session_terminated', 'session_error'].includes(e.type)))
     .subscribe(e => this.navigateToLoginPage());

    this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();

}

public initializeAuthService(): Promise<void>{

    this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);

    if (location.hash) {
        console.log('Encountered hash fragment, plotting as table...');
        console.table(location.hash.substr(1).split('&').map(kvp => kvp.split('=')));
    }

    return this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument(DiscoveryDocumentConfig.url)

        .then(() => this.oauthService.tryLogin())

        .then(() => {
            if(this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()){
                console.log("Discovery document resolved, Token does exist...", this.oauthService.getAccessToken());
                return Promise.resolve();
            }
        })

        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })       
}


public login(targetUrl?: string){
    this.oauthService.tryLogin({});

    if(!this.oauthService.getAccessToken()){
        this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer [this](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/828) it may help you

Comment: Many thanks for putting me in the right direction, The sample code I am using does work with IdentityServer but I use Azure AD B2C. I have update oauthService.events and it did work... many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sample works with IdentityServer but I am using Azure AD B2C.

I commented following code in AuthService and everything seems to be working now:

```
// this.oauthService.events
//   .pipe(filter((e) => ["token_received"].includes(e.type)))
//   .subscribe((e) => this.oauthService.loadUserProfile());
```

Comment: lol, can´t believe this was my issue haha. I thought the library was making the call automatically.